# How to get list of package in mixed case (not only uppercase)?

Tags: oracle

I use

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE','PACKAGE')
```

to get list of object but I see in oject_name column only name with uppercase letter like 'CHECKDOCNO' when I want to get CheckDocNo

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129) nonquoted identifiers are stored in uppercase. But not use quoted identifiers they are much more trouble than they are worth it. The usual way in Oracle is to use "snake case", e.g. `CHECK_DOC_NO`

Comment: If you created a package named `CheckDocNo`, Oracle saved the name in its tables as `CHECKEDDOCNO` - and there is no way to know that the name given to it initially was in mixed case. However, if you created the package and gave it the name `"CheckDocNo"` (which is a very poor practice by the way), then the name would indeed be saved in mixed case, and your query WOULD find it, it would not miss it. The fact that your query didn't return any mixed case names is good: it shows that your users followed good practices and didn't give their objects names in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm#i27570 non quoted names are always case insensitive and are stored as uppercase.

Use quoted identifiers instead.

Comment: Quoted identifiers will cause pain for everyone who ever has to refer to those objects.

Comment: That's correct but the only option if your really want those names mixed case.

Comment: True, but still not a good idea (snake case is more friendly), and doesn't help for existing objects of course.